# Optimize spark sql query with aggregate over join

Tags: apache-spark-sql, query-optimization

I have following dataframes in spark sql:

items:

```
|-- item_id: long 
|-- clicks: long 
|-- recs: decimal(16,6) 
|-- data_timestamp: long
```

campaigns:

```
 |-- item_id: long 
 |-- campaign_id: long
```

And I have this query:

```sql
select  /*+ BROADCAST(campaigns) */
 campaign_id,
 items.item_id,
 SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
 SUM(recs) AS recs , 
 MAX(data_timestamp) AS data_timestamp 
FROM items 
JOIN campaigns
ON items.item_id = campaigns.item_id
GROUP BY campaign_id, items.item_id
DISTRIBUTE BY campaign_id
```

So basically I want to distribute the data by campaign_id, and have a single shuffle. But it doesn't really work, it shuffles by item_id, campaign_id for the aggregations, and then shuffles again by campaign_id

Is there anyway I can make spark avoid the redundant shuffle?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the execution plan from "SQL Tab" for this query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'ts pretty extrange. I've been able to eliminate the extra shuffle using Dataframe API in pyspark:

```py
items.join(F.broadcast(campaigns), "item_id") \
  .repartition("campaign_id") \
  .groupBy("item_id", "campaign_id").agg(F.sum("clicks"), F.sum("recs"), F.max("data_timestamp")) \
  .explain("simple")
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
*(3) HashAggregate(keys=[item_id#1108L, campaign_id#1117L], functions=[sum(clicks#1109L), sum(recs#1110), max(data_timestamp#1111)])
+- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[item_id#1108L, campaign_id#1117L], functions=[partial_sum(clicks#1109L), partial_sum(recs#1110), partial_max(data_timestamp#1111)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(campaign_id#1117L, 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [plan_id=3443]
      +- *(2) Project [item_id#1108L, clicks#1109L, recs#1110, data_timestamp#1111, campaign_id#1117L]
         +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [item_id#1108L], [item_id#1116L], Inner, BuildRight, false
            :- *(2) Filter isnotnull(item_id#1108L)
            :  +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[item_id#1108L,clicks#1109L,recs#1110,data_timestamp#1111]
            +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=3438]
               +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(item_id#1116L)
                  +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[item_id#1116L,campaign_id#1117L]
```

As you can see there is only one exchange by `campaign_id`. And then there is a `HashAggregate` by `campaign_id` and `item_id`.

If I try to replicate it with SQL, it includes an extra exchange:

```py
spark.sql("""
  select  /*+ REPARTITION(campaign_id), BROADCAST(campaigns) */
  campaign_id,
  items.item_id,
  SUM(clicks) AS clicks,
  SUM(recs) AS recs , 
  MAX(data_timestamp) AS data_timestamp 
  FROM items 
  JOIN campaigns
  ON items.item_id = campaigns.item_id
  GROUP BY campaign_id, items.item_id
""").explain("simple")
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
Exchange hashpartitioning(campaign_id#61L, 200), REPARTITION_BY_COL, [plan_id=2971]
+- *(3) HashAggregate(keys=[campaign_id#61L, item_id#52L], functions=[sum(clicks#53L), sum(recs#54), max(data_timestamp#55)])
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(campaign_id#61L, item_id#52L, 200), ENSURE_REQUIREMENTS, [plan_id=2967]
      +- *(2) HashAggregate(keys=[campaign_id#61L, item_id#52L], functions=[partial_sum(clicks#53L), partial_sum(recs#54), partial_max(data_timestamp#55)])
         +- *(2) Project [item_id#52L, clicks#53L, recs#54, data_timestamp#55, campaign_id#61L]
            +- *(2) BroadcastHashJoin [item_id#52L], [item_id#60L], Inner, BuildRight, false
               :- *(2) Filter isnotnull(item_id#52L)
               :  +- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[item_id#52L,clicks#53L,recs#54,data_timestamp#55]
               +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(input[0, bigint, false]),false), [plan_id=2961]
                  +- *(1) Filter isnotnull(item_id#60L)
                     +- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[item_id#60L,campaign_id#61L]
```

The Dataframe API is producing a different physical plan.

Comment: Thanks @cruzlorite. 
This indeed works as expected. 
I'm now facing another issue though. If I take this query and write it to parquet, there's only one shuffle. But if I convert the dataset to JavaRDD and then call foreachPartition, it results once again in an extra shuffle.